# colorbox how make hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

```
$.colorbox({
          href:"/check.html",
          transition:"elastic",
          speed: 150,
          innerWidth:"910",
          iframe:true,
          fastIframe:false, 
          fixedPosition:fixedPos,
      onComplete:function(){

          var $iframe = $(".cboxIframe");
          $iframe.contents().find("[name='pay'] 
option[value='" + pay + "']").prop('selected', true);

       }
});
```

How to make invisible  colorbox ? `(display:none/width:0;height:0;)`

Comment: "make invisible window colorbox download?" ~~Scratches head~~

Comment: please provide some more details about your question. You want to make it transparent or hidden.

Comment: colorbox must be hidden

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to hide a colorbox popover that is being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I have used like this hope it helps.This will count upto 5 second and close automatically.You can increase count as you like.

```
 function openColorBox(){ $.colorbox({
                inline: true, href: '#FocusNews', closeButton: true, onClosed: function () { $('#FocusNews').hide(); }
            });

        }
        $(function(){
            openColorBox();

        });
        function countDown() {


           //This is to show count down
            $("#seconds").text(seconds);
            if (seconds === 0){

                $.colorbox.close();
                clearInterval(i);
            }
        }

        var seconds = 5,

            i = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
```